# Changing date format date -d '180617' +%d-%m-%Y in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I am trying to change the string in date format by using

```
date -d '180617' +%d-%m-%y
```

But the output I am getting is

```
17-06-18
```

Whereas it should be **18-06-17**

Similarly using

```
  date -d '180617' +%d-%m-%Y
```

The output is **17-06-2018**

Why is it changing day to Year and vice versa?

In my case,
Dates in the files are coming in the below format i.e.,**date +%d%m%y%H%M%S**. As I cannot change the string format for all incoming files.

How can I put the above date in date format.

For example. for the string '150617230001' 
I want the date as '15-06-2017'

Comment: The input formats are described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misunderstood the option format in date command.

date -d "format" should be as below:

```
date -d "yymmdd"
```

That is why , Your date becomes year number in your format.

```
date -d '170618' +%d-%m-%y
```

This gives you the right output.

As far you couldn't change the format in your script,said in comments, here is your needed code.

```
date -d `date +%d%m%y%H%M%S | cut -c1-6| sed -E "s/(..)(..)(..)/\3\2\1/g"` +%d-%m-%y
```

This would change the format after your possibilities..

```
18-06-17
```

Comment: just change the last character %y to %Y, so that you get full year